# Did Khalid ibn al-Walid report that he broke nine swords in the battle of Mu'tah?

Tags: war, warfare

The wikipedia entry about [Battle of Mu'tah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mu%27tah) contains an **unsourced** assertion:

> Khalid ibn Al-Walid reported that the fighting was so intense that he
>   used nine swords which broke in the battle. Khalid, seeing that the
>   situation was hopeless, prepared to withdraw. He continued to engage
>   the Byzantines in skirmishes, but avoided pitched battle. It is said
>   that Khalid killed at least one identified Arab Christian commander
>   namely Malik.

But it doesn't provide any citation for the claim.

[image: Battle of Mu'tah]

Is it true that [Khalid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khalid_ibn_al-Walid) said he broke nine swords in the battle of Mu'tah? What is the source of this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Ṭabarī](https://books.google.com/books?id=kpcopeMcXq8C&pg=PA39):

> [Khalid] went away, saying, "Nine swords were broken in my hand on the Day of Mu'tah..."

Ṭabarī attributes this account to Qais bin Abi Hazim. If you follow the footnote in Ṭabarī,you may be able to determine the original source.

Answer (score -1):

The story about nine broken swords has mentioned in syr aalam alnonlaa by alzahabi in the part of khalid bin alwaleed

Comment: Can you provide a link to or source for syr aalam alnonlaa by alzahabi?

Comment: I find links to the Arabic edition only

Comment: Well, that wont help me, but it might provide more info for the questioner, or others viewing your answer with better language skills then I have.

Comment: Add the arabic link

Comment: http://read.kitabklasik.net/2009/05/siyar-alam-al-nubala-syamsuddin-al.html?m=1